# What does it mean for a Facebook Event to be "private"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I use Facebook-C#-SDK 5.0.3 FacebookClient.Post("me/events", [parameters including "privacy" => "secret"]). The new event shows as "Private Event" on my Facebook. However, my friends see the event appear on their Wall, and when they click on the event they see it as "Public Event".

I am trying to create test events for debugging purposes, but even though I see the event as "Private Event", and when I edit the event the three checkboxes are cleared:
-- Anyone can view and RSVP (public event)
-- Guests can invite Friends
-- Show the guest list on the event page
the event is still visible and announced to all my friends. They can't RSVP, but they do get the UX to post to the event's wall.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the SDK the convention is to pass parameters in as a dynamic object or dictionary.
According to a post [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) the parameter name for setting visibility is 'privacy_type'.
So (without testing) this is how I would go about it in .Net 4:

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.privacy_type = "SECRET";
_facebookClient.Post("me/events", parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks, "privacy_type" seems to work better than "privacy". Where did you get this information? I don't see it in the link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/.

Comment: It's in the top comment. As usual Facebook leaves it to us to decipher their documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm feeling pretty stupid here. What do you mean by the "top comment"? I don't see a space for comments on this page. Are you using some kind of markup service?

Comment: The discussion section at the bottom of that page. There is a post by Arvin Sudocode.

Comment: Page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ does not contain a discussion section. However, I googled on Arvin Sudocode and found http://sudocode.net/article/373/create-an-event-using-the-facebook-graph-api-in-php/ which contains all the needed information. If there is a widely used markup service for developers.facebook.com, I would love to use it, but I just don't see the Discussion link. Maybe the original link was wrong. thanks

Comment: The page will only display a discussion section if you are logged in to Facebook.

Comment: Don't think that's it -- I'm logged onto Facebook, even see my app when I click "my apps".

Comment: @jon yeah, the discussion section on facebook developers is buggy. Sometimes it loads, other times it doesn't. And I got privacy_type from fb's old developer forum, 'cause I too had this same problem.

Comment: Thank you all for this discussion, it helped me a lot, i had troubles with events.. unfortunately the facebook documentation is incomplete but fortunately there is stackoverflow :).

Comment: For anybody looking, the link is now http://codecri.me/case/373/create-an-event-using-the-facebook-graph-api-in-php/